# What to focus on in this `perf stat` report to improve performance?

Tags: linux, optimization, perf

I have a CPU-bound workload that I want to optimize. It consists entirely of numeric computations and look-up tables, i.e. arrays in memory. I am using Linux.

`perf stat -d main` gives the following:

```
 Performance counter stats for 'main':

          1,312.53 msec task-clock                #    1.000 CPUs utilized
                 2      context-switches          #    1.524 /sec
                 1      cpu-migrations            #    0.762 /sec
             1,828      page-faults               #    1.393 K/sec
     5,923,147,477      cycles                    #    4.513 GHz
    23,334,861,436      instructions              #    3.94  insn per cycle
     2,108,821,736      branches                  #    1.607 G/sec
         8,312,184      branch-misses             #    0.39% of all branches
    29,538,565,980      slots                     #   22.505 G/sec
    23,515,015,270      topdown-retiring          #     79.6% retiring
     1,505,887,677      topdown-bad-spec          #      5.1% bad speculation
     3,359,287,895      topdown-fe-bound          #     11.4% frontend bound
     1,158,375,136      topdown-be-bound          #      3.9% backend bound
     7,328,606,538      L1-dcache-loads           #    5.584 G/sec
         1,065,578      L1-dcache-load-misses     #    0.01% of all L1-dcache accesses
            29,627      LLC-loads                 #   22.572 K/sec
             7,467      LLC-load-misses           #   25.20% of all LL-cache accesses

       1.313027809 seconds time elapsed
       1.304983000 seconds user
       0.007981000 seconds sys
```

I need help interpreting the this output, in particular identify the most significant items and what to focus on.

I can see that there are 0.39% branch misses, 5.1% bad speculations (branch speculations?), 11.4% front-end bound and 25% LLC load misses (but 22K/s only).

I don't know what can be done about fe-bound and be-bound.

Since LLC loads are only 22K/s, is this insignificant?

I can see there are lots of branches, 1.6G/sec. But since bad speculations is 5.1% and branch misses is 0.39%, is this significant? Should I focus on reducing branches?

Comment: While `perf` can sometimes be used as a tool for a global exploration, it is generally not very helpful for that. You often need to know what to search based on the code. Here the lookup table are a good indication: you can check if there is a problem with the caches based on cache misses. However, `perf` does not provide information about the L2 cache by default on most platform (which is often critical). You can precise the useful L2 events manually based on `perf list` which give you the list of *architecture-dependent* events.

Comment: If the code is sufficiently big, it can have multiple bottlenecks (regarding the section of the code being executed). Trying to analyse and optimise such code is hard. I advise you to use *precise* events so to better locate where the problem appears and analyse small portions of the code rather than the whole application.

Comment: Besides this, you currently get "3.94 insn per cycle" which is pretty good on a modern processor. The L1 refs indicates that 1 load port is saturated and another is often used so it does not seems misses are an issue at first glance (most processors do not have more than 2 load ports except recent ones). Can you provide the reference of the processor (eg. i5-9600KF)?

Answer (score 0):

> What to focus on in this `perf stat` report to improve performance?

Nothing. It provides no information that can determine if code is good or bad or could be better. If one program takes 5 seconds and gives extremely good looking stats in the summary (low cache misses, high instructions per cycle, etc), is it better or worse than an equivalent program that takes 2 seconds but gives extremely bad looking stats in the summary (high cache misses, etc)?

Start by finding out where the CPU is spending the most time (e.g. maybe using `perf report`); then (for the part of your code that costs the most time) look at the actual source code and determine if it could be using a faster algorithm, or caching results that are used again later ([memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization)), or using SIMD, or using multiple threads/CPUs.

When you're convinced the slowest part can't be improved, take a look at the 2nd slowest part (then the 3rd slowest part, then..) until you can't justify spending more time on "diminishing returns" (a 50% speed increase in something that consumes 80% of the time would be huge, but a 50% speed increase in something that consumes 1% of the time is almost worthless).